# Game running extremely slow on iOS, Unity3D

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine, ios7.1, iphone-4

I have made a very simple thing in unity3d. A cube is in the main scene and I control it via accelerometer. Just that. Simple. Now when I build my project of iOS and run it on the device using default build player settings, it runs extremely extremely slow. I don't know whats the issue. Is it iPhone 4? As its an old device. Frame rate appears to be slow in the game. I haven't checked the frame rate as of yet. But there is nothing at all in the scene except a mere cube. And I'm using the free unity version. I checked out some other posts. They say its got something to do with

> Application.tragetFrameRate

I also tried to set it to 60 in my scene's script but no gain.
Some forums said that all iOS devices have v-sync enabled and in that case .tragetFrameRate doesn't work.

I don't understand the issue plus I'm a beginner on unity.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You don't post your code to controlling the cube. It may well be the case when the controls themselves are slow and jaggy and the engine is runing fast. To test this, place an animated object in the scene and compare your performance in the editor and on the phone. A sphere moving around the scene would probably be a good choice.

Comment: Yeah. I did that too. Placed a cube and applied transform.rotate on it in the update method. Its very slow.